# Cinnamon Notifications settings

Tags: customization, notification, cinnamon

By default, in Cinnamon notifications appear for about four seconds.
How to increase this show time?

Answer (score 6):

You can set the timeout in

```
/usr/share/cinnamon/js/ui/messageTray.js
```

Look for the following line:

```
const **NOTIFICATION_TIMEOUT** = 4;
```

and set an appropriate value.

The change needs a relogin to become active.